# HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-run, hikaricp

I am encountering the following message.

```
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
```

The reason the connection is not being added appears to be due to the following message.

```
HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting=1, adders pending/running=17
```

I have no idea why this is happening . Due to this issue, I frequently fail to connect to the database.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
```

The configuration of the application I am running is as follows.

```
Spring Boot: 2.7  
HikariCP: 5.0.1  
MySQL: 8.0  
infra: Cloud Run (GCP)
```

This problem doesn't occur at regular intervals; however, it happens at least once a week.
Notably, it occurs without any particularly heavy processing happening at the time.

Is there anyone with insight into these issues? I would appreciate any ideas or guidance from someone who might have a solution.